# Is it possible to wait for a bookmark to resume from within a code activity?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I am wanting to have a code activity that will call a custom NativeActivity and wait for the result before continuing. I am able to do this through the Workflow Designer, using a PickBranch Trigger, but when I try to do it in code, it invokes the NativeActivity, but when I try to resume it I get a timeout error.

Basically, this is what I'm doing.

```
WaitForResponseBookmark nativeActivity = new WaitForResponseBookmark();

//This is where it sits and waits
var response = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(nativeActivity);
```

Here is the code for the WaitForResponseBookmark

`public class WaitForResponseBookmark : NativeActivity<RequestResponse>
    {
        protected override bool CanInduceIdle
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }`

```
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.CreateBookmark("WaitForResponseBookmark", BookmarkResumed);
    }

    private void BookmarkResumed(NativeActivityContext context,
        Bookmark bk, object state)
    {
        Result.Set(context, state);
    }
}
```

Perhaps I should not be using the WorkflowInvoker, I don't know... There doesn't seem to be much documentation on doing this, that I can find at least.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably blocking yourself. Workflow is single threaded and I think you are consuming the thread while you are waiting for something to happen. What does WaitForResponseBookmark do?

Comment: I guess I should have included that. It is a native activity that waits for the user response. I have modified the question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using a `WorkflowInvoker`. This type of workflow engine doesn't support bookmarks, you must instead use a `WorkflowApplication` engine.